# Rails view passes wrong parameters in delete link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, parameters, controller

Below is my server log.

I am passing `user_id` and `id` with the delete link from view. When it's passed, the value of `user_id` is `15067` and `id` is `1010`

While I check params putting pry method, the value of `id` is replaced by `user_id` i.e. 15067.

[image]

Here is a whole workflow:

Routes

```
delete "users/delete_role_sub_field" => "users#delete_role_sub_field"
```

Controller:

```
def delete_role_sub_field
  // Some code for destroy
end
```

View:

```
  <% @user.roles.each_with_index do |role, i| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="delete remove-description-field" href="/users/delete_role_sub_field?user_id=<%= @user.id %>&id=<%= role.id %>" data-method="delete" method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete Role Field?">
          Delete
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Any help would be appriciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `link_to` function? where u passing your params, because application works fine, if you look on your route you will see what its first params and what's its second.

Example:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
```

that will generate route like this:

```
    /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id
```

Link_to will be like this:

```
link_to ads.title, magazines_ads_path(magazine.id, ads.id)
```

and in show action:

```
def action
  @ads = Magazine.find(params[:magazine_id)).ads.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Here it is => <a class="delete remove-description-field" href="/users/delete_role_sub_field?user_id=<%= @user.id.to_s %>&id=<%= role.id.to_s %>" data-method="delete" method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete Role Field?">Delete</a>

Comment: I use simple html for creating link.

Comment: you should use link_to function everytime when u can, because if u change something that will still work.
Give me your route for this action.